# Power Seller in Virtuemart

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

How to get the power seller in virtue mart 2.0.8 ?
My Client has asked about this as like in power seller in ebay.

I have searched regarding  this content in Google. I have got the following answer in ebay ?

> Power Sellers are eBay top sellers who have consistently given great
>   customer service and maintained high sales volume on the site. They
>   provide very high levels of buyer satisfaction as indicated by the 98%
>   positive feedback that they have to maintain.
>
> We are proud to recognize their contributions to the success of the
>   eBay Community.

So in Virtue mart . How to implement Power Seller ?. Is there any default option available in virtue mart ? Kindly help.

Comment: +1 for a very good question, however I don't think what you're looking for has been developed before.

Comment: thank you .But Any body has the result

Comment: This has not be done and would be very complicated. Not only would you have to monitor seller volume, a big portion of being a power seller is the buyer feedback given. You would also need to tie in a feedback system that would allow the buyers to rate the purchase on price, shipping time, communication, etc.

Comment: oh thank you ver much for your help @BrentFriar

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a Power Seller in VM

VM is not Ebay (auction site) is a e-commerce site the reputation of the vendor is by default 100% ;)

Are you using Multivendor in VM?

Multivendor is in beta and is not ready for production sites